# angular 2: trying to load a component dynamically, getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentInjector'

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to load a component dynamically with angular2 and it's erroring out with:

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentInjector' of undefined

this is the code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Notes5',
    template: `<span #extensionAnchor></span>`
 })

export class Notes5 extends NotesBase {
    constructor(private dynamicComponentLoader:DynamicComponentLoader, private NotesService:NotesService,
                protected sliderPanel:Sliderpanel,
                protected commBroker:CommBroker) {

        this.LoadComponentAsync("src/comps/app2/notes/NoteDynamic", "TestComponent", this.extensionAnchor);
    }

    @ViewChild('extensionAnchor', {read: ViewContainerRef}) extensionAnchor:ViewContainerRef;

    public LoadComponentAsync(componentPath:string, componentName:string, locationAnchor:ViewContainerRef) {
        System.import(componentPath)
            .then(fileContents => {
                console.log(fileContents);
                return fileContents[componentName]
            })
            .then(component => {
                this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(component, locationAnchor)
            });
    }
}
```

any ideas?

regards

Sean

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is now considered deprecated.  You should use `ComponentResolver` instead.  Also, this error is due to looking for the annotations property on the component class being referenced, possibly `TestComponent`.  Is the class named `TestComponent` as well?

Comment: any samples with the new ComponentResolver

Comment: tx David, appreciate it!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original error is caused by a mismatch between the actual class name and the name of the component you are trying to dynamicall render: I.E., if you are referencing `TestComponent` the class must also be named `TestComponent`.

Your current error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentInjector'`, is caused by trying to load content into the `@ViewChild` element before the view is rendered, since you are calling it in the constructor.  You need to move your call further down the lifecycle, such as `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
constructor(private dynamicComponentLoader:DynamicComponentLoader, 
            private NotesService:NotesService,
            protected sliderPanel:Sliderpanel,
            protected commBroker:CommBroker,
            private resolver: ComponentResolver) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.LoadComponentAsync("src/comps/app2/notes/NoteDynamic", 
        "TestComponent", this.extensionAnchor);
}
```

Finally, since `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated, you should be using `ComponentResolver` instead:

```
public LoadComponentAsync(componentPath:string, componentName:string, 
                          locationAnchor:ViewContainerRef) {
    System.import(componentPath)
        .then(fileContents => {
            console.log(fileContents);
            return fileContents[componentName]
        })
        .then(component => {
            this.resolver.resolveComponent(component).then(factory => {
                locationAnchor.createComponent(factory, 0, locationAnchor.injector);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: I just added to my project, check it out (has hot-reload too now) awesome  https://github.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate/

Answer (score 0):

tx all for the support, this code works as of rc.1

```
import {
    Component, Inject, Injectable, provide, ComponentResolver, ComponentRef,
    ViewContainerRef, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {Sliderpanel} from "../../sliderpanel/Sliderpanel";
import {CommBroker} from "../../../services/CommBroker";
import {NotesBase} from "./NotesBase";
import {CountDown} from "../../countdown/CountDown";


@Injectable()
class NotesService {
    constructor(@Inject("NotesConfigValue")
                public config:{noteDefault:string}) {
    }

    showConfigValue() {
        // show the passed in param via provide("NotesConfigValue",asterisklue: {noteDefault: 'example of passing param to component via DI'}}),
        console.log(this.config.noteDefault);
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'Notes5',
    directives: [CountDown],
    providers: [
        // NotesService get's provided with a noteDefault
        NotesService,
        provide("NotesConfigValue", {useValue: {noteDefault: 'example of passing param to component via DI'}}),
    ],
    template: `<button type="button" (click)="onPrev($event)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-left "></span>
                </button>
                <hr/>
                <small>I am notes5 component</small>
                <span #extensionAnchor></span>




                `
})
export class Notes5 extends NotesBase {
    constructor(private componentResolver:ComponentResolver, private NotesService:NotesService,
                protected sliderPanel:Sliderpanel,
                protected commBroker:CommBroker) {
        super(sliderPanel, commBroker);
        NotesService.showConfigValue();
        this.me = this;
        this.slideRight = 'notes4';


    }

    @ViewChild('extensionAnchor', {read: ViewContainerRef}) extensionAnchor:ViewContainerRef;

    public LoadComponentAsync(componentPath:string, componentName:string, locationAnchor:ViewContainerRef) {
        System.import(componentPath)
            .then(fileContents => {
                return fileContents[componentName]
            })
            .then(component => {
                this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(component).then(factory => {
                    locationAnchor.createComponent(factory, 0,
                        locationAnchor.injector);
                });
            });


    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.LoadComponentAsync("src/comps/app2/notes/NoteDynamic", "NoteDynamic", this.extensionAnchor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I was using ng2-bootstrap's Modal dialog and I didn't include a reference to `viewContainerRef` in the root component.